# Sonarqube SonarLint Customisation

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

I am interested in customising SonarLint on IntelliJ, I am guessing it's possible via the sonarlint.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="SonarLintProjectSettings">
    <option name="additionalProperties">
      <map>
        <entry key="squid:S1067.max" value="20" />
        <entry key="squid:S2975" value="True" />
      </map>
    </option>
  </component>
</project>
```

Specifically I would like to disable some of the checks and increase the thresholds for others, the attached XML is my attempt at increasing the Cyclomatic Complexity for which I have failed so far to achieve, can someone point me at the relevant documentation or code for an example please

Thanks in advance

Chris

Answer (score 2):

The version 1.0 doesn't support such level of configuration. This will come progressively in next releases.