# Where is the Sonarlint Ruleset file in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint

i would like to know where eclipse keeps the ruleset for Sonarlint, so i can copy it to other Eclipses without connecting to a Sonar-Server.

As you download Sonarlint, it comes with a standard ruleset. When you connect it to a Sonar-Server it downloads the ruleset defined on the server. So where will be this ruleset stored?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default ruleset used in standalone mode seems to be defined in classes in the Eclipse Sonarlint plugin jar (e.g. in `org.sonarlint.eclipse.core_2.2.1.201608261350-RELEASE.jar`) . This means that it's currently not possible to change this ruleset (unless you want to try and reverse engineer it). Your only option is to connect each machine to a SonarQube server.

It seems there are plans to add more customization support in the future (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33604816/741249)).

Comment: Not exactly the answere i hoped for, but thanks.
Funny thing is, if you connect to a server the configuration(ruleset) will be saved in .sonarlint\storage\yourservername\global\active_rules\java-sonar-way.pb file. But if you copy the server config and the ruleset to another eclipse it won't be recognised by sonarlint.